# take input for array from user in java

Tags: java

I am working on a java code to get an array of integers from the user and then remove the integer in a selected index by the user. My code is already done but I don't know how to get array input from the user.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test11 {
    public static int[] removeTheElement(int[] arr, int index) {
        if (arr == null || index < 0 || index >= arr.length) {
            return arr;
        }
        int[] anotherArray = new int[arr.length - 1];

        for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            if (i == index) {
                continue;
            }
            anotherArray[k++] = arr[i];
        }

        return anotherArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner adnan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        System.out.println("Original Array: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
        System.out.println("Index to be removed: ");
        int index = adnan.nextInt();
        arr = removeTheElement(arr, index);
        System.out.println("New Array: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You can make use of the ArrayList object. Or create a dummy array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code in the `main()` to make it work for accepting arrays input from user.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Enter the size of array: ");
 final int size = scanner.nextInt();
 int[] array = new int[size];
 
 System.out.println("Enter the elements to array: ");
 for (int loop = 0; loop < size; loop++) {
  array[loop] = scanner.nextInt();
 }

 System.out.println("Original Array: " + Arrays.toString(array));
 System.out.println("Index to be removed: ");
 int index = scanner.nextInt();

 array = removeTheElement(array, index);
 System.out.println("New Array: " + Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the array as a string like : 1 2 3 4 ..., and then extract and cast the values. Or you can ask the user for the size of the array (number of elements that the user wants to insert ) and then loop to scan and save each element.

The first case :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   String[] stringArray = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
   int[] parsedValues = new int[stringArray.length];
   for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
       parsedValues[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i]);
   }
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parsedValues));
 }
```

The second case :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] parsedValues = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size && scanner.hasNextInt(); i++) {
            parsedValues[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parsedValues));
  }
```

Comment: How can I do this? @Zouhair Dre